# SAPUI5 odata.v2.ODataModel Call back of batch request is invoked before batch request is complete

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

I'm having a little issue with my batch request, when the odata model is submitted and triggered, the `that.readAndUpdateSercicePeriodPlans(oService).then(function(oSerciceO)` in the callback is triggered before the batch return the result

As you can see using my debugger, the call back function is triggered  :

[image]

but the network didn't return the result yet :

[image]

Below is the code, what I am doing wrong? :

```
odataMod = this.getModel("Service");
odataMod.setUseBatch(true);
var aDeffGroup = odataMod.getDeferredGroups();
//add your deffered group
aDeffGroup.push("deletionGroup");
_.forEach(periodPlanArr, function(periodPlanToDel) {
    odataMod.remove('/ProjectTaskServicePeriodPlanCollection(\'' + periodPlanToDel.ObjectID + '\')/', {
        groupId: "deletionGroup"
    });
});

oGlobalBusyDialog.setText("Deleting Period Plans in progress");
oGlobalBusyDialog.setTitle("Updating data Model");
oGlobalBusyDialog.open();
//This trigger the batch request 
odataMod.submitChanges({
            // deffered group id
            groupId: "deletionGroup",
            success: function(oData) {
                sap.m.MessageToast.show(oData.toString());
                var aErrorData = sap.ui.getCore().getMessageManager().getMessageModel();
                var msg = aErrorData.getData();
                var oService = _.find(oNoneAssignedTaskModelData, function(oSewrv) {
                    return oSewrv.ObjectID === uniqueByID[0].ParentObjectID;
                });
                oGlobalBusyDialog.setText("Updating oModel in progress");
                oGlobalBusyDialog.setTitle("Updating data Model");
                // ISSUE : This below  function is invoked before even the batch request is complete , why ?! 
                that.readAndUpdateSercicePeriodPlans(oService).then(function(oSerciceO) {
                        oGlobalBusyDialog.close();
                        //Logic USER STORY 3423: Get Internal Indicator PeriodPlan and update the employee nternal Indicator PeriodPlan

                    },
                    error: function(oError) {
                        var oResponse = JSON.parse(oError.response.body);
                        sap.m.MessageToast.show("Fehler: " + oResponse.error.message.value);
                    }

                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging all night and drinkind redbull I've finally found the issue :

```
var aDeffGroup = odataMod.getDeferredGroups();
aDeffGroup.push("deletionGroup");
//I must set the deffered groups after pushing the ID or else it won't be added 
this.setDeferredGroups(aDeffGroup);
```

I'd recommand to avoid adding same group twice - I had some issues because of that.

```
     odataMod = this.getModel("Service");
            odataMod.setUseBatch(true);
            //var aDeffGroup = odataMod.getDeferredGroups();
            //aDeffGroup.push("deletionGroup");
            that.setModelDeferredGroup(odataMod, "deletionGroup");
// the function 
    setModelDeferredGroup: function (oModel, sGroup) {
        if (oModel && sGroup) {
            var aDeferredGroups = oModel.getDeferredGroups();
            if (aDeferredGroups.indexOf(sGroup) < 0) {
                aDeferredGroups.push(sGroup);
                oModel.setDeferredGroups(aDeferredGroups);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Chrome Filter icon will only be red if there is some value in the filter.:)

Comment: Hello Bernard, but later when I click on play in the chrome the network doest display the btatxh request, that means that the callback got triggered before even the bath finish, it's weird

Comment: I think I've found my issue, I must set the deffered group after I push my deffered group ID : ``` odataMod.setDeferredGroups(aDeffGroup);```